# First-Order Transient Circuit with Capacitor

Tags: circuit-analysis, transient

Consider the following circuit, where the switch is in position A for a long time and moves to position B at time \$t = 0\$. For \$t \geq 0\$, \$v_C(t)\$ and then \$v(t)\$ need to be found.

[image: Transient RC circuit]

I found \$v_C(t) = (10 - 6e^{-2.6t})\ \mathrm{V}\$, which is the given correct answer. However, I am not sure of the correct answer (not given) for \$v(t)\$. I am getting three different answers using three different approaches:

1. If I use \$v(t) = v(\infty) + [v(0^+) - v(\infty)]e^{-t/\tau}\$, I get \$v(t) = -2.31e^{-2.6t}\  \mathrm{V}\$.
2. If I use \$v(t) = 5i_C(t)\$, where \$i_c(t) = C\frac{dv_C(t)}{dt} = 3.12e^{-2.6t} \mathrm{A}\$ (differentiating the earlier expression for \$v_C(t)\$) is the current through the capacitor leaving the positive terminal, I get \$v(t) = 15.6e^{-2.6t}\ \mathrm{V}\$.
3. If I use KVL for \$t \geq 0\$, I get \$-v(t) - 10 - 8i_C(t) + v_C(t) = 0\$, which gives \$v(t) = -30.96e^{-2.6t}\ \mathrm{V}\$.

Which is the correct answer? The approaches make sense to me logically, but why are they giving different results?

Comment: If you look at only t = 0, you will find that your first approach results in the correct answer.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the rate of decay in your expression. Your time constant is 0.2 * (5 + 13), so your rate of decay is \$v(t)e^{-t/\tau}\$ = \$v(t)e^{-t/2.6}\$ = \$v(t)e^{-0.38t}\$

Comment: My time constant is correct (consistent with the answer given for \$v_C(t)\$). \$\tau = R_{\mathrm{Th}}C = 1/2.6\ \mathrm{s}\$; hence, \$1/\tau = 2.6/\mathrm{s}\$.

Comment: \$\tau = RC = 2.6\$ s,  not \$1/2.6\$ s

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right! The examiner marked it correct, but I spotted the mistake in my solution for \$\tau\$. Recalculating gives similar values for \$v(t)\$ for approaches 1 and 2 but with opposite signs. I think maybe \$i_C(t)\$ should be entering the capacitor's positive terminal since it's perhaps charging instead of discharging; doing this gives the correct answers for approaches 2 and 3 also.